# html.partial with dynamic append using script (Razor)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

trying to do the below

```
$('#body').append('<div id=\"'+  name + 'div\"' + '>' + '\'' +  @Html.Partial("_ChatWindow")  + '\'' + '</div>');
```

_chatwindow.cshtml is just

```
<button>test</button>
```

but i get a run time syntax error at the opening angle bracket of the partial class. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a string for partial view content:

```
$('#body').append('<div id=\"'+  name + 'div\"' + '>' + '\'' +  '@Html.Partial("_ChatWindow")'  + '\'' + '</div>');
```